# How to suppress TS6133 error with TypeGraphQL and TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeorm, typegraphql

I'm starting with TypeGraphQL and TypeOrm. I begin fallowing the "Getting started" guide in https://typegraphql.ml/docs/getting-started.html. I change the class in the guide with my own class so I have this:

```js
@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class Photo {

    @Field(type=>ID)
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Field()
    @Column()
    name: string;

    @Field()
    @Column()
    description: string;

    @Field()
    @Column()
    filename: string;

    @Field()
    @Column("real")
    views: number;

    @Field()
    @Column()
    isPublished: boolean;
}
```

But when I compile I get the error:

`src/entity/Photo.ts(8,12): error TS6133: 'type' is declared but its value is never read.`

What I need to do to suppress this error in TypeScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you did not configure tsconfig.json for TypeScript correctly, it detects an error in the compile phase.
I am sharing a sample tscongif.json file.
With the TypeORM and TypeGraphQL binary, it is comfortable and to meet the desired requirements. You can change it later.

You can solve problem that friend who answered before me said [**@Julien TASSIN**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6299938/julien-tassin), but I would like to remind you that you know that main source of problem is through the TypeScript compilation rules.

example **tsconfig.json** file for TypeORM + TypeGraphQL

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    // "incremental": true,                    /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "esnext",                        /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                      /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    "lib": ["esnext", "esnext.asynciterable"], /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    // "allowJs": true,                        /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                        /* Report errors in .js files. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                      /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    // "declaration": true,                    /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                 /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                      /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                        /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    // "outDir": "./",                         /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    // "rootDir": "./",                        /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "composite": true,                      /* Enable project compilation */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./",                /* Specify file to store incremental compilation information */
    // "removeComments": true,                 /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                         /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                  /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,             /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,                /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    // "strict": true,                         /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    // "noImplicitAny": true,                  /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,               /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,            /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,            /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,   /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                 /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                   /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                 /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,             /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,              /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,     /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "moduleResolution": "node",                /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                        /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                            /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                         /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                        /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                            /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,   /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    // "esModuleInterop": true,                /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,               /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */
    // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,           /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                      /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                         /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    "experimentalDecorators": true,           /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true             /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the type param for the `@Field` of your id :

```
@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class Photo {

    @Field(()=>ID) // here is the difference
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Field()
    @Column()
    name: string;

    @Field()
    @Column()
    description: string;

    @Field()
    @Column()
    filename: string;

    @Field()
    @Column("real")
    views: number;

    @Field()
    @Column()
    isPublished: boolean;
}
```